# ESP8266 exception 29

Tags: arduino, esp8266

[image]

I have Wemos D1 connected to pc in AP mode. When I send a lot of message it give me an exceptión. Baudios: 921600.

Comment: I have same issue with esp8266-01. Any solution with Adruino?

Comment: hi, you have one ore some functions that need a lot of exertion. in me case. I have in arduino a function to splits the mesage that recive from Esp8266 and it make a bottleneck giving that exception. I change split function to .readString() and work it

Comment: Long time gone, I know. Do you still have your faulty script? I'be curious to see it, because I get the same exception, but I'm running the ESP as Wifi client instead of as an accesspoint. Maybe, we find some matches or have you allready solved the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I am getting the same exception from my ESP8266, so I did some research. It was tricky to track-down a list of exception codes, but I found one in an ebook published by Neil Kolban and downloadable here: https://leanpub.com/ESP8266_ESP32. (Well worth the $5 suggested price, IMO.)

Anyway, to your question: Exception 29 is 'storeprohibitedcause,' meaning that your code tried to write to a protected area in memory.

The value given for excvaddr shows the virtual memory address (0x00000000) that caused the exception. Kolban's book gives this link to a map of the ESP8266's memory addresses: http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_memory_map.

Your code faulted at program counter (epc1) 0x40202556, information that can help you figure-out what part of your code caused the offending memory write. There are debuggers that you can use to track this down, but, in my own case, I know where the problem is so I haven't researched that avenue any further.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about what debuggers you used? And in addition to that, what your resolution you took? I too have the same problem.

Comment: @AdityaTalpade, I didn't use any debugger. I just did some digging on the internet, found the ebook I mentioned, and went from there. For whatever it was that I was struggling with (don't remember now), that was enough to let me find the remedy.